# How to add same perspective in Eclipse in Other Projects?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

I have saved a custom perspective in one of my projects and now I want to use that same again in my other java project but upon looking for perspectives category, my custom perspective is not showing up in the new project but is visible in the previous project.

**I want my perspective to applied on all java projects which I ever I open automatically.**

Is there any way we can export our perspective to a file format (like XML or something which eclipse can read on importing it again) and upon working on new project we can simply import them using the export file.

I don't know any solution to it but I have attached images for your references:

Java CP 2 is my custom perspective but it is not visible in another project.

How can I do something so that it is visible globally (in my IDE) and at present, I have to manually set up a perspective for each project I open.

Screenshot 1 - *Java CP 2 Perspective*

[image: Screenshot 1 - Java CP 2 Perspective]

Screenshot 2 - *Java CP 2 Perspective is not present*

[image: Screenshot 2 - Java CP 2 Perspective is not present]

Comment: Are these projects in the same workspace? Perspectives are global to a workspace but are not shared between workspaces.

Comment: Both projects are in a different workspace.